# Finding the fixed point..

Tags: matrices, quadratics, transformation, fixed-point-theorems

I don't quite understand this question.

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a=14,b=−25$ and $c=−7$. There are two fixed points at $x_1$
and $x_2$, where $x_1>x_2$. How to get the value of $x_1$? In two decimal places.

Just click on the link below for my working, I think I got it wrong. Can someone help me on this?

[Click on this link for the working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4FEZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

let $x$ be a fixed point, then $f(x)=x$, solve this equation.
Or you can think of a function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and find the roots

Answer (score 0):

You should not be solving for $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

You should be solving for $$ax^2+bx+c=x$$

that is the definition of a fixed point.